# hide sticky navigation when browser resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design

I have create sticky navigation for my project and this sticky navigation must show only on desktop mininum 980px and hide below 980px on the fly when I resize my browser.

here is my code

```
if ($(window).width() > 980) {      
$('.stickynav a').on('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
});
$(window).on('scroll',function() {
    var scrolltop = $(this).scrollTop();

    if(scrolltop >= 132) {
      $('.stickynav').fadeIn(250);
    }

    else if(scrolltop <= 210) {
      $('.stickynav').fadeOut(250);
    }
});
}
```

I create in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cXH5g/1/)
how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in css with media queries.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 979px) {
  .stickynav{
    display: none;
  }
}
```

I've updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cXH5g/2/

Media queries allows you to define css for specific devices/screen size.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for the answer, but that not work. sticky menu should hide when first time user open page and show only when user scroll page. This is your code on fullscreen http://jsfiddle.net/cXH5g/2/embedded/result/

Answer (score 0):

the best way to do this is using CSS3 media queries.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

but if you want to do it with jquery:

```
$(function(){

if ($(window).width() > 980) {
    alert($(window).width());
    $('.stickynav').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scrolltop = $(this).scrollTop();

        if(scrolltop >= 132) {
            $('.stickynav').fadeIn(250);
        }

        else if(scrolltop <= 210) {
            $('.stickynav').fadeOut(250);
        }
    });
}
});
```

I put an `alert` to see when you code should work.
check **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cXH5g/3/)**

Comment: hi, that is my initial code. the problem with that code is you must refresh page when you resize screen less than 980px and the menu will hide. you can check your code in fullscreen mode here - http://jsfiddle.net/cXH5g/3/embedded/result/  try scroll page then resize the browser less than 980px. Thanks